# How accurate is QR code scanning?

Tags: qr-code

I want to use QR code for a crucial part of my app. How accurate is QR code scanning?

I use iphone4 or equal quality scanner phone.

Comment: You should be more accurate in asking your question and demonstrate some more search effort. Have you made tests yourself? For example write an app that consistently takes a photo of a qr-code and compares the extracted content with predefined content. You could also have a look at the qr-code spec to see what kind of error correction is employed.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "accurate". Is it probability the qr code can be found in the image or may it be the chance that some wrong content is extracted from the qr code?

Comment: I mean the wrong content is extracted from the qr code. Ex. If i put www.google.com ito my qr. when i scan it how accuracy it will be? Ex. I scan for 100 time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QRCode use the Reed–Solomon error correction algorithm with four error correction levels :

- Level L (Low)    7% of codewords can be restored.
- Level M (Medium)     15% of codewords can be restored.
- Level Q (Quartile)   25% of codewords can be restored.
- Level H (High)   30% of codewords can be restored.

A reading won't return you wrong values : if the QRcode can't be read it won't return anything, so it's quite "accurate".

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code for more explainations.

Comment: Can the www.google.com be read like www.goofle.com? In some low light or bad condition? Or it will return nothing if it can't read correctly?

Comment: Like I said, it won't return you a wrong value. If the QRcode can't be read (low light or bad condition), it won't return anything.

Comment: I am quit interested in this question because I created a QR code for a contact and then when I scan the QR code image with several apps (iOS and android both ), nearly 7, only one app which created that QR Code returned exactly every fields and sub fields  of that contact, others either missed any field(s) or combined/missed some sub fields.